# What Javascript or Jquery library can I use for GANTT charts with IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, gantt-chart

I'm looking to make a GANTT chart with Sharepoint 2010. I'm aware of the built in functionality to make them with Sharepoint but need to make a separate one.

Comment: Use Highcharts .. http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: or [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)............;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use kendo UI. They have a free and paid for version.
[Gantt Chart](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index)

Works with IE 7 and above.

Answer (score 1):

RadiantQ's [jQuery Gantt Package](http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/) gives you the most complete Gantt feature set with very good Customer Support.